# Android Google Map is not displaying

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working in android. I want to show simple google map in my activity.

This is my main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <com.google.android.maps.MapView
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/mapview"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:clickable="true"
 android:apiKey="mykey"
 />
```

This is my Activity:-

```
 package com.quepplin;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class GooglemapActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
MapView mMapView;
mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
mMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

}
```

}

I have created google key successfully. But whenever i run my application then it crashes. and following error is displaying in logcat:-

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView

 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView

   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
```

Please help me what mistake i have done. I am very new to create google map. I waiting for suggestion.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am not wrong then

```
public class GooglemapActivity extends Activity
```

should be

```
public class GooglemapActivity extends MapActivity
```

and in your manifest file..

```
 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

And your `application build platform is Google-api`

Answer (score 6):

Use MapActivity instead for Activity

```
public class GooglemapActivity extends MapActivity {
```

Answer (score 1):

**public class GooglemapActivity extends MapActivity {**

Comment: user370305, Kevin Pius,KK_07k11A0585 Thank you sir thank you so much... love you all...